# Helm Config-Map with yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to access a file inside my helm templates as a config map, like below. I get an error as below.

However, it works when my application.yml doesn't have nested objects (Eg - name: test). Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

**config-map.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
 name: {{ .Release.Name }}-configmap

data:
 {{.Files.Get “application.yml”}}
```

**application.yml:**

```
some-config:
 application:
   name: some-application-name
```

**ERROR:**

```
*ConfigMap in version “v1" cannot be handled as a ConfigMap: v1.ConfigMap.Data: ReadString: expects ” or n, but found {, error found in #10 byte of ...|ication”*
```

Comment: Thanks for the formatting update Rico.

Comment: So, I was able to fix it. The issue was that the indentation was wrong, which was fixed by adding '{{ .Files.Get "application.yml" | nindent 4}}'

Comment: Great, I added what I see with the same files you specified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have an indentation issue on your `application.yaml` file. Perhaps invalid YAML? If I try your very same files I get the following:

```
○ → helm template ./mychart -x templates/configmap.yaml
---
# Source: mychart/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
 name: release-name-configmap
data:
  some-config:
 application:
   name: some-application-name
```

Answer (score 3):

As per [documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/#formatting-templates):

> Templates should be indented using two spaces (never tabs).
>   Template directives should have whitespace after the opening braces and before the closing braces.

finally it should looks like:

```
{{ .Files.Get "application.yml" | nindent 2 }}
or 
{{- .Files.Get "application.yml" | nindent 2 }}
to chomp whitespace on the left
```